# Java- Wrapping a function in another class function

Tags: java, class, oop

i want to check if my Java Code is OOP enough,

Say i have this class called **Shop** and inside that class I have a method called **getAverageEarnings**

I have another class called **Simulator** and inside it have a wrapper function to wrap the **Shop** class **getAverageEarnings**

I have to hide the Shop class from the user.

Eg:

```
public class Shop{
   public double getAverage(){
     return (this.total/5);
   }
}

public class Simulator{

   Shop shop;

   public Simulator(){
      shop = new Shop();
   }

   public double getAverage(){
       return shop.getAverage();
   }
}
```

Is this a good practice or a bad practice in terms of OOP-ness?

Comment: Not getting completely what you are looking for, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I am unsure if it's a good practice to have a function that wraps another class function

Comment: This isn't a valid question for SO, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask But this is an interesting question nontheless, so: yes, it's a good practice when applied properly.  It's called delegation pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern Please confirm that you've read this, I want to flag this as "opinion-based", but most importantly I want to make sure that you've got your answer.

Comment: @FilipMalczak thanks for pointing to delegation pattern. You can flag it as opinion-based. Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understand your question is, you want to call a method of Shop class into Simulator class but you don't want that Shop will involve in outer world. right.

If this the case, then I would suggest to follow below steps to design your module.

i) Declare Shop as a Abstract, because you have tightly coupled logic in that and create protected method getAverage.

ii) Extend Shop in Simulator or any fragment class you like and call getAverage with supper method.

hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks but can i know what's the difference between doing this and Delegation pattern?

Comment: If you have lots of classes and interface, so I would be better to use a design pattern for routing a input request in effective manner.

But if you are having small scale application, then going with few Abstract and Interfaces will be fine.

Also make sure, which methods you want to put in Interface(lossly couple) and which you want in Abstract(Tightly coulple).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you want to hide the shop class from outside world right, you can try following,

-Make the shop class abstract and access specifier private.
-Extends shop in simulator. 
-By extending shop all members will be available in simulator so define GetAverage() in simulator and compute average in it.